# System.Speech.Recognizer saving to string

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I'm making a C# program which uses System.Speech.Recognition and I need to save the words said at a point in my code. Such as the user can say "Google cats" and it would save "cats" to a string this way I can use this string to Google search the string which in this case is "cats". My code so far can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/mtD3Re26).

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Why? That makes me feel like I'm not talking to humans. Imagine if I was at the library asking the librarian where a book was and I just said "Where's Moby Dick?" and when he or she's done just leave. Is there a special reason why we can't use "Hi" || "Thanks"?

Comment: We are not having a discussion here. This is not a discussion forum. It's a Q&S site. Please take the time to read the [faq] and [ask] and learn how things work here. The fact that we do things differently is the _reason_ the site is so successful.

Comment: And, BTW, when people post links, they generally mean for you to read them.

Comment: I did read it. I'm just saying, I respect your authority. It just feels unhuman to not start off anything without a greeting.

Comment: You clearly didn't read it well. Again, we are not having a conversation here. You ask a question, you get an answer, maybe not right away. Someone asks a question four years from now, they get the same answer you got today.

Comment: My personal theory is that stripping salutations from questions probably increases SO's hit rate on Google, a good thing IMO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get user input from Speech?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878565/get-user-input-from-speech)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by loading a grammar that matches `google <any text>`. Create a grammar builder, append `google` and append dictation.

Put this at the point where you load grammars:

```
GrammarBuilder googleGrammarBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
googleGrammarBuilder.Append("google ");
googleGrammarBuilder.AppendDictation();
listener.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(googleGrammarBuilder) { Enabled = true });
```

And put this in your `SpeechRecognized` method:

```
if (e.Result.Text.StartsWith("google "))
{
    string googleQuery = e.Result.Text.Remove(0, 7);
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String.Concat("http://google.com/search?q=", googleQuery));
}
```

The `Process.Start` line will open your default browser with the Google link.