# Add part of Speech Recognition as Variable in C#

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

Hey I'm working on creating a Speech Recognition that will Google what you ask it to.  **My question is how can I get it to recognize part of the statement as a variable?**

For example:

*Search Google for theory of relativity*

How could I get it to detect only the first "Search Google For" then add the rest of the statement in as a variable
"https://www.google.com/#q= + variable??"

(Yes, I copied the above sentence from someone else who asked the question but didn't get any answers)

So my edit to this question is if I use the substring how could I implicate that as a new variable? If it's not too much to ask some sample code would help a ton!

Comment: Already asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210353/register-part-of-speech-statement-as-variable?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get user input from Speech?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878565/get-user-input-from-speech)